# Flex :: <mx:transitions> not working Properly in my flex project ?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

I used:

```
    <mx:Transition fromState="*" toState="">
                                         //universal_title name for TitleWindow id another stage .loginform is panel id another winidow        
             <mx:Sequence targets="{[Universal_title,loginform]}">

            <mx:Sequence id="sequence1" filter="show" >
                <mx:WipeUp/>
                  <mx:Resize duration="500" easingFunction="Bounce.easeOut"/>
                <mx:SetPropertyAction name="visible" value="true"/>

            </mx:Sequence>


            <mx:Move filter="move"/>
            <mx:Sequence id="sequence2" filter="show" >
                <mx:SetPropertyAction name="visible" value="true"/>
                <mx:WipeUp/>
            </mx:Sequence>
        </mx:Sequence>
    </mx:Transition>
        </mx:transitions>
```

But not show animation . What I did wrong in code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's quite a few things that could be going wrong. First off, is your toState definitely an empty string, or do you mean to have toState="*"? for your targets, I'd make sure Universal_title is the correct name - your mx:Move tag isn't going to do anything, it needs some sort of to / from values (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/effects/Move.html) and there's probably a few other bugs, but that's just from a quick glance.

Comment: quoo thank you very much . it's information more useful to me